# Tengo problemas con password verify

Tags: php, html, web

buenos días tengo una duda mi problema es al momento de de verificar la contraseña no me deja loguearme y solo me muestra la pagina en blanco y me redirige al mismo archivo de configuración del login, mi pagina cuenta con dos tipos de usuario, normal y admin, ejemplo de hash ejemplo de llave hash $4y$10$CLzoXY7wtoTFyqAxDi3pVOqCUCeLuthiEAfi2tc76lFNxgNYqCbas
Este es mi código

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('config/dbconfig.php');

if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])) 
{
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['email']);
    $contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['contrasena']);

    $login_query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email' AND contrasena='$contrasena' LIMIT 1";
    $login_query_run = mysqli_query($conexion, $login_query);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($login_query_run) > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($login_query_run))  
                {
      if (password_verify($contrasena, $row['contrasena'])) 
     {
        foreach($login_query_run as $data)
        {
            $user_id_usuario = $data['id_usuario'];
            $user_nombre = $data['nombre'].' '.$data['apellido'];
            $user_email = $data['email'];
            $role_as = $data['role_as'];
        }

        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
        $_SESSION['auth_role'] = "$role_as"; // 1 = admin, 0 = usuario
        $_SESSION['auth_user'] = [
            'user_id_usuario'=>$user_id_usuario,
            'user_nombre'=>$user_nombre,
            'user_email'=>$user_email,

        ];

        if($_SESSION['auth_role'] == '1') 
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Welcome to dashboard";
            header("Location: admin/index.php");
            exit(0);
        }
        elseif($_SESSION['auth_role'] == '0') 
        {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are logged in";
            header("Location: admin/index.php");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['message'] = "invalid email or password";
        header("Location: ../login.php");
        exit(0);

    }
}
}
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['message'] = "You are not allowed to Access this file";
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit(0);
}
?>
```

Así aparece en el navegador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si guardas en la BD la contraseña encriptada **$4y$10$CLzoXY7wtoTFyqAxDi3pVOqCUCeLuti2tc76lFN**, aquí no puedes comparar la contraseña, ya que el hash nunca es igual:

`AND contrasena='$contrasena'`

entonces elimínalo y obtén el usuario mediante su email:
`"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email='$email'";`

y posterior ya verificas si el password es válido o no con tu línea:

`if (password_verify($contrasena, $row['contrasena'])){}`

Otra cosa, aquí no sé qué estás haciendo:

`foreach($login_query_run as $data){}`

realmente también la podrías quitar, piensa que ya estas obtenido un arreglo con datos desde la BD aquí:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($login_query_run)) {}`

Por ultimo cambie `header("Location: ../login.php");` por `header("Location: login.php");`, no estoy seguro, pero creo que no puedes usar *../*

Te aconsejo que uses [sentencia preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para obtener mayor seguridad ante la [inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php/53134#53134) y así te actualizas a lo actual.

**Posible ejemplo:** (mysql::perpare)

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('config/dbconfig.php');

// Reseteo
$ok = true;
$email = $contrasena = '';

// El boton del formulario esta definido
if(isset($_POST['login_btn'])) :

    // Obtenemos datos formulario
    $email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'] ?? '';

    // Email invalido
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) :
        $ok = false;
        $_SESSION['message'] = "invalid email";
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit(0);
    endif;


    // Datos son verdaderos desde el formulario
    if ($ok && $email && $contrasena) :

        // Query
        $query = "SELECT `id_usuario`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `email`, `contrasena`, `role_as` FROM usuarios WHERE email = ?";

        /* crear una sentencia preparada */
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $query)) :

            /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email); // "s" significa que el valor de $email es de tipo 'string' (cadena)

            /* ejecutar la consulta */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            /* almacenar el resultado */
            $filas = mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

            // Existen registros
            if ($filas > 0) :

                /* ligar variables de resultado */
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id_usuario, $user_nombre, $appellido, $user_email, $contrasena_bd_hasheado, $role_as);

                /* obtener valor */
                if (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) :

                    // Validas la contraseña
                    if (password_verify($contrasena, $contrasena_bd_hasheado)) :

                        // Creas tus sesiones
                        $_SESSION['auth'] = true;
                        $_SESSION['auth_role'] = $role_as; // 1 = admin, 0 = usuario
                        $_SESSION['auth_user'] = [
                            'user_id_usuario' =>$user_id_usuario,
                            'user_nombre'     =>$user_nombre,
                            'user_email'      =>$user_email
                        ];

                        // Depende del roll, envias mensaje dashboard o You are logged in
                        if($role_as == 1) : 

                            $_SESSION['message'] = "Welcome to dashboard";
                            header("Location: admin/index.php");
                            exit(0);

                        elseif($role_as == 0) :
                            $_SESSION['message'] = "You are logged in";
                            header("Location: admin/index.php");
                            exit(0);
                        endif;


                    // Password incorrecto
                    else :
                        $_SESSION['message'] = "invalid email or password";
                        header("Location: login.php");
                        exit(0);
                    endif;
                endif;
                
            // No existen datos en la BD 
            else :
                $_SESSION['message'] = "invalid email or password";
                header("Location: login.php");
                exit(0);
            endif;
            
            /* cerrar sentencia */
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        endif;

    // Algun input vacio desde el formulario
    else :
        $_SESSION['message'] = "invalid email or password";
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit(0);
    endif;
endif;
?>
```